# Oracle SQL - Where statement - IS NOT NULL and NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue with the **WHERE** statement in my sql.

I want all not null values but I also want to exclude records where the value is X or values is Y

```
WHERE FIELD_A IS NOT NULL AND FIELD_A != '4' FIELD_A OR != '5'
```

but the results are not correct...
I thought maybe...

```
 WHERE FIELD_A IS NOT NULL AND FIELD_A NOT IN ('4','5')
```

but I believe this is bad practice and wont yield reliable results....

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this does exactly what you want:

```
WHERE FIELD_A NOT IN ('4', '5')  -- don't use sigle quotes if the values are numbers
```

Almost all boolean operators return `NULL` when either argument is `NULL`.  `NULL` values filter out rows in the same way that "false" values do in a `WHERE` clause.

There is no problem with being explicit, as in your second example.

Comment: NULL is neither false nor true in a where clause, though. It would be more accurate to say that NULL is interpreted as "not false and not true".

Comment: the numbers are stored in a varchar2 - whould i still omit the single quotes?

Comment: @Ronald . . . If the value is a string, then definitely use single quotes.

Answer (score -2):

As Gordon said you can also use this :

```
WHERE  FIELD_A != '4' AND  FIELD_A  != '5'
```

It is exactly the same thing.

Comment: No.  You need `AND` not `OR`.  Hence why `IN` and `NOT IN` for lists of constants are so handy.

Comment: Use AND and not OR. That where clause gets allways TRUE